# How to avoid a FileNotFoundError with os.listdir

Tags: python, python-3.x, listdir

I'm developing a loop where each csv in a specified directory is re-sampled and then exported into a new file. I'm getting a FileNotFoundError despite trying with various folders and using exact folder paths.

```py
# Specify folder name
serial = '015'

# Specify directory (note - '...' substitute for the full path used back to the drive letter)

root_dir = '...\\CleanTemps\\{}\\'.format(str(serial)) 

#loop
for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):

        print(filename)

        # Pull in the file
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

This prints a list of the eight files .csv files in that folder. However, when using the following code to pull in the file (one-by-one as a df to modify, I receive the FileNotFoundError:

```py
#loop
for filename in os.listdir(root_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):

        # Pull in the file
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your file is compose from root_path + your file name, you can use :

```
from pathlib import Path 

root_path = Path(root_dir)

for filename in os.listdir(root_path):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):

        # Pull in the file
        df = pd.read_csv(root_path/filename)
```

or you can use:

```
for filepath in root_path.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: With `pathlib` you can do even better! `for filepath in root_path.glob("*.csv")` and `filepath` is now only CSVs and already concatenated with the root.

Comment: Thank you, I added your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the full (or relative) path to the file, not just its name, this path is based on the root of your files, and you can use `os.path.join` to build it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root_dir, file_name))
```